# How to display multiple string values, based on boolean fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report that pulls contact information (Name, address, etc). Each contact can be associated with one or more counties. The way the application was designed, each county is a yes/no field. There are roughly 70 of these.

To keep this report from being unwieldy, instead of adding 70 fields to it, I want to have a text field of a comma separated list of String values for each of the applicable counties where Boolean is true.

I've done IIF conditional formatting before.

```
IIf([County]="True", "CountyName", "")
```

But I've only done them in 1-to-1 (one condition, for one field, for one textbox). How do I apply 70 conditions, across 70 fields, to one textbox?

EDIT:
Upon further discussion (below), it sounds like I need a custom VBA function that loops through the fields and creates a conditional string of values.

I'm a VBA novice. I'd appreciate any assistance on creating a function that loops through the applicable counties in the record and creates a comma separated list.

Comment: 70 fields is too many for single expression. Will need a custom VBA function. Really should normalize data structure. Instead of 70 fields, should be a related dependent table with a record for each county associated with client.

Comment: I realize what it "should" be. But normalizing this application isn't on the table right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example assumes the only YesNo fields are the "roughly 70" county fields. Procedure can be in report module and call function from a textbox or in a general module and called from anywhere: `MakeList([ID])`. In textbox, precede expression with = sign.

```
Function MakeList(intID As Integer) As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strList As String
Dim x As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE ID=" & intID)
For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    If rs(x).Type = dbBoolean Then
        If rs(x) = True Then strList = strList & rs(x).Name & ","
    End If
Next
If strList <> "" Then MakeList = Left(strList, Len(strList) - 1)
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

An alternative is to expand the `If Then` condition statement to exclude fields by name if only a few. Another is to reference fields by index. If all the county fields are say index 10 - 80 then `For x = 10 To 80` and the test for Boolean type can be eliminated. Index begins with 0 so the 1st field is index 0. Fields are pulled in the order they are listed in table design when using the * wildcard.

Improve performance by building a query object that includes only the ID and county fields and save it then open recordset from that query (or copy/paste very long statement into VBA). Use index to reference fields.

Comment: This is a GREAT baseline for me! I'll start working on this now, and follow up soon as I can.

Comment: This worked BEAUTIFULLY! It did, however, highlight that there are more yes/no fields than just the counties. However, can I just modify the Select statement? Yes, that would mean typing out the 70 counties by hand - unless there is another option.

Comment: There are roughly 20 additional fields. I think the index will work. I'm going to try that now! All the counties are next to each other, so, that should nail it. I'll comment an update soon. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm! THANKS!

Comment: I should have mentioned option of building a query object that pulls only ID and county fields. Then VBA opens recordset from that query instead of table.

Comment: You lost me. Either way, the situation has morphed into now wanting these fields in an Excel export. In fairness, because this question was answered, I'm about to ask another question. I've been working at this, and thought I had the solution, but the code makes Access unresponsive. I don't think my employer knows the extent of how bad this db is, and overestimates my ability to custom code fix it.

Comment: Lost you where? You do know how to build a query object in Access? Code can reference a query as well as a table to open recordset. Yes, concatenation code like this can cause poor performance. But you did say it worked. What changed?

Comment: Ah! Yes, building a query I know how to do. Even though this is OOP, I get confused when the word "object" is used. And I, more or less, know how to reference a query in VBA. It worked for the report that can be exported into PDF. Now, it's wanted to export to Excel .... Annnnd, nevermind! I just realized the report could be exported to Excel - as well as PDF - and the PDF design didn't make the Excel export look unwieldy. We'll see if my employer is satisfied with said outcome.